# How to install and run SIlverlight application in MAC OS X?

Tags: macos, file, silverlight, xap

I have a Silverlight application ("**file1.xap**"). How do I install it in MAC OS X?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696434/what-is-needed-to-run-silverlight-out-of-browser-application-on-mac?rq=1

Comment: My requirements See this question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757296/how-to-install-and-run-silverlight-application-through-applescript

Comment: See this question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757296/how-to-install-and-run-silverlight-application-through-applescript